# Find the value of $\,\, \lim_{n \to \infty}\Big(\!\big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)\big(1+\frac{2}{n}\big) \cdots\big(1+\frac{n}{n}\big)\!\Big)^{\!1/n} $

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, factorial

What is the limit of:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{2}{n}\Big)
\cdots\Big(1+\frac{n}{n}\Big)\bigg)^{1/n}?
$$

By computer, I guess the limit is equal to $\dfrac{4}{e}$, but I have no idea about proving that.

Thank you for your any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $f(n)=[\prod_{i=0}^n (1+r/n)]^{1/n}$ Then, $\ln f(n)=1/n\sum_{r=0}^n\ln (1+r/n)\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty}\ln f(n)=\int_{0}^1 \ln (x+1) dx=\ln 2-\int_{0}^1 \dfrac{x}{x+1}dx=2\ln 2-1\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty} f(n) =4/e$

Comment: I knew there was a Riemann some sumwhere (haha) there! Looks like we have to take the logarithm of both sides first.

Answer (score 6):

We shall use that:

**Fact.** $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^{\!1/n}
\!\!\!\!\!\longrightarrow\mathrm{e}.$

Then
$$\bigg(\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{2}{n}\Big)
\cdots\Big(1+\frac{n}{n}\Big)\bigg)^{1/n}=
\left(\frac{(2n)!}{n^n n!}\right)^{1/n}=\left(\frac{2^{2n}\frac{n^n}{n!}}{\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n)!}}\right)^{\!1/n}=4\frac{\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^{1/n}}{\left(\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)^{1/n}}
\longrightarrow\frac{4\mathrm{e}}{\mathrm{e}^2}=\frac{4}{\mathrm{e}}.
$$

Note. The Fact above can be shown as follows:
$$
\log \left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\to\int_0^1\log x\,dx=-1.
$$